# How to use Valgrind and KCachegrind for code visualization on Windows without Linux subsystem. Struggling with Valgrind execution on Windows

Tags: valgrind

Seeking assistance to use Valgrind and KCachegrind for code visualization on Windows without Linux subsystem. Struggling with Valgrind execution on Windows, need guidance to resolve the issue.

I was trying for the visual dynamic analysis of C code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Struggling with Valgrind execution on Windows, need guidance to
> resolve the issue.

***`Valgrind`*** is a Linux program which does not support Windows. ***`Valgrind`*** heavily relies on Linux internals, that’s why ***`Valgrind`*** does not support Windows. There are some Windows tools (like *Deleaker*) having the same purpose

***`KCachegrind`*** also is a Linux-only tool. You can compile from sources **`QCachegrind`** - as far as I know, there is no binary distributed.

Comment: Valgrind also runs on FreeBSD (about as well as on Linux), Solaris (fairly well in some cases) and macOS (not very well). There are a few other unofficial ports.

Comment: @PaulFloyd does freeBDS and Solaris help with Windows? They are all *nix like systems

Comment: No but what you said is quite wide of the mark.